# Problems ingesting events into Seq from Serilog

Tags: c#, logging, serilog, seq

I'm working on a C# application that sends Logs on a remote **Seq** Sink by Serilog **(Serilog.Sinks.Seq)**. It was working good until I added some more logs; After that it just sends some of the logs to seq. I tested File sink but it works without any problem and writes all logs to the file, but the seq is still have same problem. I even tested Seq on local computer, but no profit.
So I have installed **Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching** hoping to solve the problem. but unfortunately I did not found any documentation or examples how to configure and enable it in my project. the only code I found is https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-periodicbatching that I don't understand. anyone know how to use it to solve this problem with Seq? I need a simple example.
I'm using latest version of Serilog and PeriodicBatching.
**Update 1:**
Here is the File log that is produced correctly. In the seq the three last logs are dropped.

```
2021-02-06 09:45:36.164 +03:30 [INF] ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀|  
2021-02-06 09:45:36.180 +03:30 [INF] Application Start.  
2021-02-06 09:45:36.180 +03:30 [ERR] It is a fresh OS  
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at SenderConsole.Program.scanClientAndSendIfDifferent() in D:\Programing\SysWatch\SenderConsole\Program.cs:line 434  
2021-02-06 09:45:36.195 +03:30 [DBG] getCurrentClientConfig() Started.  
2021-02-06 09:45:36.289 +03:30 [DBG] getCurrentClientConfig()==> CpuChanges  
2021-02-06 09:45:36.305 +03:30 [DBG] getCurrentClientConfig()==> StorageChanges  
2021-02-06 09:45:36.383 +03:30 [DBG] getCurrentClientConfig()==> RamChanges  
2021-02-06 09:45:36.398 +03:30 [DBG] getCurrentClientConfig()==> MotherboardChanges  
2021-02-06 09:45:36.414 +03:30 [DBG] getCurrentClientConfig()==> OsChanges  
2021-02-06 09:45:36.492 +03:30 [DBG] getCurrentClientConfig()==> NicChanges  
2021-02-06 09:45:36.679 +03:30 [DBG] getCurrentClientConfig()==> PrinterChanges  
2021-02-06 09:45:36.695 +03:30 [DBG] getCurrentClientConfig()==> DomainChanges  
2021-02-06 09:45:36.883 +03:30 [DBG] getCurrentClientConfig()==> iSMBIOSChanges  
2021-02-06 09:45:36.914 +03:30 [DBG] getCurrentClientConfig()==> AppChanges  
2021-02-06 09:45:36.929 +03:30 [DBG] getCurrentClientConfig()==> AntivirusChanges  
2021-02-06 09:45:36.929 +03:30 [DBG] getCurrentClientConfig() Ended.  
2021-02-06 09:45:36.929 +03:30 [DBG] configsAreDifferent() Started.  
2021-02-06 09:45:36.929 +03:30 [INF] Configs are different.  
2021-02-06 09:45:36.929 +03:30 [DBG] serializeByJson() Started.  
2021-02-06 09:45:37.148 +03:30 [DBG] serializeByJson() Ended.  
2021-02-06 09:45:39.210 +03:30 [FTL] Unable to connect to the remote server  
2021-02-06 09:45:39.210 +03:30 [INF] Sent to DB.  
2021-02-06 09:45:39.210 +03:30 [INF] Application End.
```

Comment: Seq has settings in the website that dictate the largest size payload it will accept. Depending on your structured log properties they could get dropped. I found I had to increase mine to be quite large. There's also client side settings in the seq sink you can use to control the sizes of the batches. Reducing message count and batch size so that the setting in the server was a multiple will probably help you. It helped me and my logs were no longer dropped. The seq sink is *already* a periodic batching sink if you look at its source.

Comment: Thanks for comment @pinkfloydx33. How can I configure batches in client side?

Comment: There's several optional properties when calling `WriteTo.Seq`, you might start there. I'm on mobile so don't know off top of my head

Comment: Have you read https://docs.datalust.co/v2.0.0/docs/getting-started ?

Comment: Also, your question is very confusing as the PeriodicBatchingSink is an internal detail (when you asked yesterday and deleted that question, this was a prime reason people were not able to figure out what you were asking - the solution to things like that is to edit the question, not delete it!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update based on your edit:**

It appears the last few messages before your program ends are the ones being dropped. You need to flush the logger to ensure Serilog forces and waits for any pending logs events before the application has time to exit:

```cs
public static void Main() 
{
   try
   {
       // Program Logic here
   } 
   finally
   {
       Serilog.Log.CloseAndFlush(); 
   } 
}
```

**Original answer:**

Structured logging properties can become quite large which leads to larger HTTP requests and increased CPU requirements to process them. The reason your events are getting "lost" is because there are limitations imposed by both Seq (the server) and the Serilog Sink that attempt to alleviate these concerns. Messages (single events or entire batches) can be dropped by either the client or the server depending on the specific configuration and the message/batch size. Notice I said "batch"; calling the `Seq` extension method chained against `WriteTo` will add a `PeriodicBatchingSink` (an implementation of the `IBatchedLogEventSink`) which *wraps* the `SeqSink`. So you don't need to try and wrap it yourself--it's already done.

So how do you alleviate your problems? Well first, you can update the settings on the Server. Seq recommends against this, however there are definite use-cases, especially if you are sending a lot of properties. Under `Settings -> System -> Ingestion` you can modify the "Raw ingestion payload limit" and/or the "Raw event body limit" settings. Personally, I leave the former at the default value and increased the latter based on some calculations we've made based on how we will configure the Sink itself:

[image: Seq Server Settings]

Take heed of the underlined warnings! Make sure you understand the implications of modifying these settings.

Now on the client side you have a few options. The `Seq` extension method has a few parameters that can be used to tweak the logger's behavior.

| Parameter | Default Value | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `eventBodyLimitBytes` | 262,144 | The maximum size, in bytes, that the JSON representation of an event may take before it is dropped rather than being sent to the Seq server. Specify `null` for no limit |
| `batchPostingLimit` | 1,000 | The maximum number of events to post in a single batch |

If the *batched* events do not fit within `eventBodyLimitBytes` after they have been serialized into "compacted JSON", then the **entire** batch will be dropped. The `batchPostingLimit` is used by the `PeriodBatchingSink` to determine how many messages to queue up before it sends the events to the inner sink (which performs the serialization/dropping). You might also consider changing the minimum log level as it defaults to `Verbose` or passing in a `LoggingLevelSwitch`

```cs
var maxSizeBytes = 512 * 1024; // 512KB, double the default
var batchLimit = 100; // 1/10 the default
logger.WriteTo.Seq(
    "http://seq.server.com", 
    eventBodyLimitBytes: maxSizeBytes, 
    batchPostingLimit: batchLimit, 
    restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Information
);
```

Configuring a smaller batch size could decrease the chance that you will exceed the byte limit but that will cause *more* HTTP requests to be sent which could be a problem of its own. Now remember, you also need to adhere to the configuration of the server; your combined event size needs to be less than the "Raw ingestion payload limit" to ensure that an entire batch isn't dropped and a single event must be smaller than "Raw event body limit".

Since I don't know anything about your actual events, I can't advise on the appropriate settings here. I can only point you in the correct direction. All I can say is that you should perform some calculations that make sense based on the server settings, knowledge of your events (and their attached properties) and your business requirements:

Your other option is to use an "Audit" sink. In this mode, Serilog will **throw an exception** if a log message cannot be transmitted to the target medium. When using the `Seq` extension method against `AuditTo`, a `DurableSeqSink` is used instead. Logs are persisted to disk first (as temporary storage) and then shipped to Seq *one at a time*. If you really must guarantee log messages aren't dropped (and that, if they are you are notified) this is the way to go. There's overhead here; messages must be written to a file, you need a new HTTP request per event **and** you need to guard all of your logging statements with `try/catch`. The latter point is IMO the biggest reason against this, particularly if you are using the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger` abstraction around Serilog as consumers typically expect logging to be exception free.

You can also make use of log filters/`LoggingLevelSwitch` and Serilog's `Filter.ByExcluding` to control the messages that will be sent. Furthermore, you might also consider tweaking the Destructuring depth and size to ensure that nested properties and collections are only serialized up to a maximum size.

```cs
logger.Destructure.ToMaximumDepth(5) // default 10
      .Destructure.ToMaximumStringLength(1000) // made up value, default is int.MaxValue
      .Destructure.ToMaximumCollectionCount(10) // made up, default is int.MaxValue
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did what you say but not working. I will update my question to write the digested logs on file and Seq.

Comment: When it runs without a slow exception it digest all the logs without problem.

Comment: @MahmoodJenami Are you flushing the logger before your program ends? It makes sense the last few messages are dropped if Serilog hasn't had time to deliver the batch. See my edit above

Comment: You saved my day @pinkfloydx33. **Serilog.Log.CloseAndFlush()** worked for me.    Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MahmoodJenami glad to help. But please do keep the rest of the answer in mind. Seq can drop messages/batches if the size gets too large or if the network request fails, etc

Comment: Yes @pinkfloydx33, currently I have a log event with 360KB of size and Seq drops it. how can I configure to solve this?  should I set eventBodyLimitBytes more than 360KB?

Comment: Max size defaults to 256k. So yeah, I would increase it. I doubled it in the example above.

Comment: @MahmoodJenami sorry, you also need to set "raw event body limit" in the server. It too defaults to 256kb. So you need to increase both (client and server) as mentioned above